# Form input moves up when focused

Tags: ionic-framework

When I focused input form, this form moves up in the screen.

This is for a application mobile on Ionic 3.

```
<ion-content>
<div class="bg" [hidden]="Keyboard.isOpen()"></div>
<div class="bg2"></div>
<p (click)=goToRegisterPage()>Sign up!</p>
<div class="form">
  <h3>Sign in</h3>
  <hr class="hr">
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="dark" floating>email</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="dark" floating>password</ion-label>
      <ion-input></ion-input>
  </ion-item>  
  <button class="button-form">-> CONTINUE</button>
  <div class="separator-form">
    <hr>
    <h6>or</h6>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <img class="img-form" src="../../assets/imgs/icon -G+.png"/>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

I expect that the form don't move when I focused or when the keyboard moves up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following line :

```
<div class="bg" [hidden]="Keyboard.isOpen()"></div>
```

the [hidden] attribute acts on the css property **display : block/none** of the that DIV.
So when the keyboad is open, which means the input has the focus, that div disappears.

Now if you want that Div to still disappear without moving the other parts of the page you need to do the following :

```
<div class="bg" [ngStyle]="{'visibility' : Keyboard.isOpen() ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}"></div>
```

Comment: Appears the same problem.

Comment: I solve the problem with this post on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197469/ionic-2-disable-scrolling-on-login-form-input-focus

Answer (score 0):

In your imports inside `app.module.ts` ensure the following:

```
[...]
IonicModule.forRoot({
  scrollPadding: false,
  scrollAssist: false
}),
[...]
```